# FTP Server for WinXp

Tags: windows-xp, ftp, boot

I'm looking for an FTP Server that is able to launch on system startup and that a non-admin user is unable to close. I've tried xLight Ftp Server but while it launches on startup it doesn't start the server nor does it have an option for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really like [FileZilla Server](http://filezilla-project.org/) it's open source software distributed free of charge under the terms of the GNU General Public License

Be sure to click the *"Download Server"* button and not the client.

Comment: We have this on a bunch of Windows game servers to pull logs, works well, easily configurable from a GUI

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP Professional includes Microsoft's IIS which comes with an FTP Server. So there's no need for 3rd party Software.

Go to Start->'Control Panel'->'Add/remove Programs' and choose the 'Add/remove Windows Components' button from the bar on the left. Highlight the item 'Internet information services (IIS)' If it is unchecked, check it, then click 'details.'

The components you will need are: 'Common Files,' 'File Transfer Protocol (FTP) Service' and 'Internet Information Services Snap-In.' Uncheck any others then click next. IIS will configure itself, and you may be prompted for the XP CD.

After IIS has been installed, an FTP site is automatically created for the directory 'c:\inetpub\ftproot.'

Next step is to configure your new site using 'Internet Information Services/FTP Sites' in 'Administrative Tools'.

For more Details see [How to setup an FTP server in Windows using IIS](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/setup-ftp-server-in-windows-iis/)